# monit file sha1 checksum not working

Tags: monit

I am using monit 5.14 to monitor the checksum of a file. I have the below config in the monitrc
check file file1.jar with path /home/lib/target/myjar.jar
if changed sha1 checksum then stop

I have already defined stop. However when I run monit status I always see that the File is unmonitored.

Am i missing anything else ?

Answer (score 0):

Its weird. 
I had a big process name  like abracadabara12343.jar and just reducing it to jar worked !!